# Convert a web app created in VS 2010 ASP.NET 4.0 to ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-application-project

I've made a web app in VS 2010 and by default, I think it uses the .NET Framework 4.0. Problem is, the server that's going to run it doesn't have 4.0.

Is there a way to downgrade the project? I'm not really knowledgeable with web hosting or web servers so I don't really know which is easier, downgrading the project or upgrading the web server. It's a company web server by the way, so I'm not sure about the legalities and stuff. It's free though, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and go to properties.  Under the "Application" tab, change the "Target Framework" from 4.0 to 3.5.  That should do it provided you are not using any code features unique to 4.0.

If you can update the server easily, I would recommend that so that you have the 4.0 framework available to you going forward.  The .NET framework is a free download.

Comment: @o6 what if it's deployed in the web server? if upgrading the server is the better option, are there other requirements? or they just have to run the 4.0 installer?

Comment: If the application is already deployed (I guess it's deployed but has errors running?), you would have to run the 4.0 installer and then, when completed, go into the Web Site's IIS properties and adjust the Framework setting on the "ASP.NET" tab to 4.0.  The site would also have to run in a seperate Application Pool than anything running in a lower framework.  Creating a new application pool is easy (right-click, new, etc) and then you just need to point the Web Site to that new application pool.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project name and select `Properties`  On the `Application` tab, you should see a `Target framework:` dropdown.